# Save form and redirect to same url - Fails to save the changes - Django

Tags: python, django, forms, post

My HTML http://127.0.0.1:8000/orden-detalle/1

```
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{% if orden.anulado == True %}
    <ul>
        <li><input id="estado_reanudar" name="estado" value="FALSE" type="radio">Anulado</li>
        <input type="hidden" name="pk" value="{{ orden.pk }}">
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Reanudar Orden" />
        </li>
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <ul>
        <li><input id="estado_reanudar" name="estado" value="TRUE" type="radio">Activo</li>
        <input type="hidden" name="pk" value="{{ orden.pk }}">
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Anular Orden" />
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

My views.py

```
def orden_detalle(request, pk=False):
    if pk:
        orden = get_object_or_404(Orden, pk=pk)
    else:
        orden = Orden()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        estado = request.POST.get('estado')
        pk = request.POST.get('pk')
        orden.anulado = estado
        orden.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('ordenes:orden_detalle', args=(pk)))

    template = 'ordenes/orden_detalle.html'
    return render(request, template, locals())
```

Terminal

```
[19/Nov/2015 16:03:17] "POST /orden-detalle/1 HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[19/Nov/2015 16:03:17] "GET /orden-detalle/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 2885
```

My urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ordenes/$', views.orden_listado, name='orden_listado'),
    url(r'^orden-detalle/(?P<pk>[-\d]+)$', views.orden_detalle,name='orden_detalle'),
]
```

When I change "estado" of "orden" using the form throws me the error 302.
It is supposed to be changing my html, but does not.
Where is the error?

Comment: 302 is not an error, it's a response for redirection. In your case it's your `HttpResponseRedirect` that caused this.

Comment: @ShangWang As I can fix it?

Comment: There's no error message so there's nothing to fix. What's your problem with your current approach? You need to learn more about the basic knowledge for web development, for 302 response: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302

Comment: @ShangWang when I print "orden.anulado" after "orden.save()" shows me that "orden.anulado" changes. But it fails to see the change in the database. Fails to save the changes. The field is a Boolean.

Comment: Then you need to edit your question to reflect this. The only thing might not work is that you have `pk = request.POST.get('pk')` but the `pk` is never used. Other than that I think your code should work.

Comment: @ShangWang The 'pk' use it to indicate that "orden" belonging redirection. http://127.0.0.1:8000/orden-detalle/1 <------ pk

Comment: And why do you query Orden from the database three separate times?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I already corrected, but still save.

Answer (score 0):

Change the value in radio buttons:

```
 <li><input id="estado_reanudar" name="estado" value="0" type="radio">Anulado</li>

 <li><input id="estado_reanudar" name="estado" value="1" type="radio">Activo</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works now. I modified my "view" to this:

```
def orden_detalle(request, pk=False):
    if pk:
        orden = get_object_or_404(Orden, pk=pk)
    else:
        orden = Orden()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        orden.anulado = not orden.anulado
        orden.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('ordenes:orden_detalle', args=(pk)))

    template = 'ordenes/orden_detalle.html'
    return render(request, template, locals())
```

And my html:

```
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{% if orden.anulado == 1 %}
    <ul>
        <li>Anulado</li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Reanudar Orden" />
        </li>
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <ul>
        <li>Activo</li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Anular Orden" />
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endif %}
</form>
```

I assumed that the code 302 was a mistake, I was wrong. The documentation indicates that subclass HttpResponseRedirect returns an HTTP status code 302.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302